# Semi-random name generator

Tags: system-agnostic, tools, generator

Does anyone know of a good online name generator that can be set up to create *random names with culture-specific flavour*? (Meaning, for example, names that *sound like* Russian, Norwegian etc etc.)

Comment: related: [Online resource for names by culture](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134). Several of the answers there include name generators.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online resource for names by culture](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134/online-resource-for-names-by-culture)

Comment: @okeefe I don't think my question would be a duplicate of the question you cite. Sure, the answers to that Q bring up random generators, but the Q itself doesn't seem to ask for that, whereas I do here. (In fact, that Q is too broad. Coming to think of it, mine would be a good candidate for community wiki as well, if we still have that.)

Comment: As @AlexP suggested, the [Story Games Names Project (pdf)](http://www.bullypulpitgames.com/projects/names/book/sgnp_final_05_no_art.pdf) is a list of lists of names broken into types of genres, including cultures. It's easily randomizable (lists are labeled 1-20) but, of course, finite. Russian is included (as are Finnish and Swedish) but not Norwegian, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

**[Everchanging Book of Names](http://ebon.pyorre.net/)**

A flexible name generator with 'chapters' for names from earth culture (Africa to Oceania), as well as several well known settings (WHFRP to Startrek) as well as this it's possible to make a custom library for it to generate names from (it'll apply linguistic rules and generate *new* names out of the list you provide)

*Very Snazzy*

Comment: The primary thing that makes this useful is that it's not cloud-based.  However, it's not free for anything but the core stuff so if it's not basic fantasy names you lose out.

Comment: @CatLord but you can expand it with your own libraries if you wish. It takes some effort but it can be quite fun too.

Answer (score 5):

**[Aaron Sherman's mkname CGI script](http://www.ajs.com/~ajs/cgi-bin/mkname.cgi)**

Lists several countries/regions (from African to Icelandic to Polish to Welsh) and generates a list of 10 names for both male and female characters matching the selection (some languages, like Hebrew, Iranian and Icelandic, also include non-latin characters in the names).

Answer (score 3):

**[Rinkworks Name Generator](http://www.rinkworks.com/namegen/)**

You can select from several pre-configured options (Chineese Names, Greek Names, Hawaiian Names, ...) or enter a [custom pattern](http://www.rinkworks.com/namegen/instr.shtml) describing the name format after which you want to have names generated.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.apocwords.net/systems/names.html does Afghan, African, American, Ancient, Arabic, British, Bulgarian, Chaos, Chinese, Dutch, Dwarvish, Eastern, Egyptian, Egyptian, Elvish, Empire, European, Finnish, French, German, Halfling, Hebrew, Indian, Iranian, Iraqi, Irish, Israeli, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Latin, Norwegian, Pakistani, Phillipino, Portugese, Roman, Russian, Spanish, Swedish, Turkish, and Vietnamese

Answer (score 1):

The random generator on [Behind the Name](http://www.behindthename.com/random/) is always my go to source, especially because I run/play 7th Sea and need a host of culturally diverse names.  Simply check whatever roots you want and away you go.  Normally I select it to add three middle names when searching for a first name that fits the bill.  The best part is that you can just hit the refresh button to have the same parameters reloaded, back button once to change constraints.